# After typing code, I get an error that says "not called in your program", and an error that says btn is an enexpected token

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button go to a link. icecub helped my on the code, but when I run this

```
function handleRedirect(){
    window.location = "https://max0815.wixsite.com/theaviary";
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    const btn = document.getElementById("button27");


    btn.addEventListener("click", handleRedirect, false);
});
```

It claims that the part where is says "function(event)", that "event" is defined, but not called in your program. Furthermore, when I run the program, it highlights the "b" in "const btn =" and says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token (136:10)" How would I approach this problem? How should I fix it?
[image]

Comment: Your current code's syntax is correct - it does not result in an unexpected token syntax error. (remove `event` from the parameter list, and the code's syntax will still be correct)

Comment: When I run it, the line "const btn = document.getElementById("button27");
" has a syntax error with "b" in "btn" highlighted.

Comment: which browser are you running it in? That syntax is fine, but all I can think of is if you're running it in some antique browser like IE and therefore `const` isn't recognised as a keyword.

Comment: Yep, and even IE11 supports `const` (to a limited extent), guess you can use `var` instead

Comment: I'm trying to run it in code.org.

Comment: @Snow I added the picture. Do you think that btn is invalid?

Comment: Syntax looks fine. Either your IDE or your browser is extremely ancient - use `var` instead of `const`. (and look around to upgrade to a more modern environment)

Comment: I just had a look at `code.org`, but I can't have a play around with it without signing up. Your image adds to the mystery because `const` is highlighted, suggesting the JS engine involved does indeed recognise it - but in that case I can't see any reason why it's complaining...

Comment: (And just as a check on my own sanity - I just pasted that function into the Chrome console, it didn't complain of any syntax errors.)

Comment: Tell code.org to get with modern development, even IE11 had `const`, and that was 6 years ago, which is an eternity in web development terms

Comment: @Snow yeah I know. Just sent a message asking code.org to look into the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a *linter warning*, not an error. It's warning you that you defined an argument called `event` that you never used, which means that including it in your code just results in noise: remove it from the function definition:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
```

A similar warning would be probably displayed for the following function:

```
function foo() {
  const bar = 'barbar';
  return 'baz';
}
```

because the `bar` variable is defined, but never used (just like your `event` parameter).